# DB2 Querying a table for both DISTINCT and COUNT(DISTINCT)

Tags: sql, count, db2, distinct

I'm trying to query distinct Update_Date but also return a column that counts the total number of distinct Update_Date

The table right now (Only Update_Date is being queried):

```
Update_Date  |  Status
-------------------------------
2022-03-01   |  1
2022-03-02   |  2
2022-03-03   |  1
2022-03-03   |  2
2022-03-03   |  3
```

My SQL right now:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT Update_Date, 
COUNT (DISTINCT Update_Date) AS Update_Date_CNT
FROM TABLE
```

The expected result should be

```
Update_Date  |  Update_Date_CNT
-------------------------------
2022-03-01   |  3
2022-03-02   |  3
2022-03-03   |  3
```

Right now I'm getting an error:

> DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42803] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0119N  An expression starting with "CLC_YYMM" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.  SQLSTATE=42803

If I run the SELECT with only one of the two columns, no errors are thrown.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT Update_Date
FROM TABLE
```

```
Update_Date  
-----------
2022-03-01   
2022-03-02   
2022-03-03
```

```
SELECT 
COUNT (DISTINCT Update_Date) AS Update_Date_CNT
FROM TABLE
```

```
Update_Date_CNT 
---------------
3
```

I'm guessing it's because the Update_Date_CNT column returns 1 row but the Update_Date column returns 3 rows, and the syntax so far doesn't say to "repeat" the '3' returned by Update_Date_CNT for each Update_Date row?
I read in another post about joining but the error message mentions GROUP BY - how do I fix this error?

Comment: If you are using DB2, why have you tagged SQL Server?

Comment: Ah sorry the website recommended adding that tag, apologies about the mislabel. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer, I don't use DB2 so there may be a better method, but either using a CTE or a derived query seems to work with DB2 11.1

**Option #1**

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Update_Date) AS Update_Date_CNT
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT DISTINCT t.Update_Date, cte.Update_Date_CNT
FROM   YourTable t CROSS JOIN cte
```

**Option #2**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Update_Date, totals.Update_Date_CNT
FROM   YourTable t CROSS JOIN 
       (
         SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Update_Date) AS Update_Date_CNT
         FROM YourTable
       ) totals
```

**Results:**

| UPDATE_DATE | UPDATE_DATE_CNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 | 3 |
| 2022-03-02 | 3 |
| 2022-03-03 | 3 |

Comment: Option 1 is what I was looking for - the WITH syntax looks pretty similar to other code we have right now.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `COUNT()` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Update_Date, COUNT(*) OVER () AS Update_Date_CNT
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cross join` as follows

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Update_Date
    FROM TABLE
) T1
, 
-- cross join /*new version*/
(
    SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Update_Date) AS Update_Date_CNT
    FROM TABLE
) T2
```

or

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT update_date, 
  (
    SELECT 
      Count (DISTINCT update_date) AS Update_Date_CNT 
    FROM 
      TABLE
  ) Update_Date_CNT 
FROM 
  TABLE
```

Comment: Yes, but best not to use the antiquated ANSI-89 style joins.  Using an explicit CROSS JOIN makes the intent clearer.